# Taking derivative of an equation

Tags: derivatives, error-function

I'm trying to apply a boundary condition to the following equation:

$$c_A = {K_o}\int_{0}^{u} e^{-u^2} du + K_1$$

where
$$u = \frac{x}{\sqrt{4Dt}}$$

and ${K_o}$ and $K_1$ are constants.

The boundary condition is:

$$\frac{\partial c_A}{\partial x} = 0$$

However, when I try to take the derivative with respect to both sides of the equation, I just seem to get $0 = 0$.
In other words, I'm not getting a value for one of the constants; so I think I must be doing something wrong.

Taking the derivative of the constant, $K_1$ with respect to x yields zero.  Taking the derivative of the integral (error function) term, I think
results in:

$$\frac{\partial \operatorname{erf}(Ax) }{\partial x}=\frac{2A}{\sqrt\pi}e^{-u^2}$$

where A is equal to:

$$A = \frac{1}{\sqrt{4Dt}}$$

If I'm right then the only way the derivative of the erf expression in the original equation is equal to zero is
if the entire derivative of the erf expression equals zero, so I wind up with $0 = 0$ and no solutions for either constant.

What am I doing wrong?  Thanks.

Comment: Try the Leibniz integration rule.

Comment: @Ricardo:

If $K_o$ is equal to zero, then the integral portion of the equation goes away, and I'm left with $c_A$ always equals $K_1$.  But there is definitely a profile with x.  The boundary condition is only true at $x_o$, so I'm not understanding your answer.

Comment: The solution is the general solution for Fick's 2nd law.  I'm going to drop the "A" subscript for simplicity.

$$\frac{\partial c}{\partial t} = D\frac{\partial ^2 c}{\partial x^2}$$

The boundary condition that I listed is true at $x = x_o$ for all times, even at t = 0.

Comment: $c(x,0) = c_o$.      So, it is a constant value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124070/discussion-between-rdemyan-and-ricardo-cavalcanti).